# What is the dimension of an orbit G.x?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups

Let X be an affine/projective variety and G an algebraic group acting algebrically on X. Pick x in X, which are the properties  of the orbit G.x? I've seen examples in which it can be both open or closed. I also see people writing dim G.x, does that mean G.x is some sort of algebraic subvariety of X?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the term "constructible set" is a useful search term here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard result in the theory of algebraic groups is the following.

*Theorem:* Let $G$ be a connected algebraic group acting on  a variety $X$. Then each orbit $Gx$ is irreducible and open in its closure (hence is an irreducible variety in its own right). Its boundary is a union of orbits of strictly smaller dimension. In particular, orbits of minimal dimension are closed (so closed orbits exist).

So indeed orbits have a dimension.